# Create Empty Json with Labelme

Tags: json, machine-learning, computer-vision, labelme

Here is an example Labelme window, with 5 polygon labels marked (want to detect some old video tapes). And yes i can easily save its json file
[image]

But there are some images, with out any labels (which are not video tapes). Such as this image below:
[image]

I want to save this last image to the database too, which could help to train better and more robust detection algorithm. But i can't save it's json file, since there aren't any polygons drawn on this.

Is it possible to create these kind of unmarked images' json files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2844

glenn-jocher's answer: "to use background images in training you simply add these images to your dataset. No labels are required for background images."

in short, just add the labelless images without json files